# Self joining table to get datetime from next row as a column in current row Transact SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

There's other questions similar to this have been answered, however main problem here is there is no `rowID` (`objectID` etc.) so that the table can be self-joined.

My current code works fine, however since it needs to be interpreted by INSQL (a linked server), for some reason anything with `ROW_NUMBER()`  will not work

Wondering if anyone has experience with doing the same thing as the code below, however NOT using `ROW_NUMBER()`, `COUNT(*)`, `TOP(*)` or things like that?

EDIT:
Just mention that due to limitation with the linked server, any possible neat trick must be done outside of the quoted query 'SELECT...'... It's quite a pain :(

Many thanks in advance

```
SELECT TOP 20000
  StartQ.DateTime AS StartTime,
  EndQ.DateTime AS EndTime,
  StartQ.PlyRemaining,
  StartQ.PlyTarget,
  StartQ.PlyNumber as PlyNumber,
  StartQ.PileNumber AS PileNumber,
  'ST3P' AS STACKER_ID
FROM
( SELECT TOP 20000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DateTime] ASC) RowNum, *
FROM 
OpenQuery(INSQL, 'SELECT [DateTime], 
PlyRemaining = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS_TO_STACK],
PlyTarget = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS],
PlyNumber = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS] - [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS_TO_STACK],
PileNumber = [DA2.N_ST3P_PILENUM]
FROM WideHistory
WHERE DateTime > "2011-06-01 00:00:00"
AND DateTime <= "2011-12-12 00:00:00"
AND wwRetrievalMode = "Delta"
')  ) StartQ INNER JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 20000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DateTime] ASC) RowNum, *
FROM 
OpenQuery(INSQL, 'SELECT [DateTime], 
PlyRemaining = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS_TO_STACK],
PlyTarget = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS],
PlyNumber = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS] - [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS_TO_STACK],
PileNumber = [DA2.N_ST3P_PILENUM]
FROM WideHistory
WHERE DateTime > "2011-06-01 00:00:00"
AND DateTime <= "2011-12-12 00:00:00"
AND wwRetrievalMode = "Delta"
') 
) EndQ ON EndQ.RowNum = StartQ.RowNum + 1
```

The results look like

```
StartTime           EndTime             PlyRemaining PlyTarget PlyNumber PileNumber STACKER_ID
------------------- ------------------- ------------ --------- --------- ---------- ----------
2011-06-01 00:18:13 2011-06-01 03:20:25 NULL         0         NULL      NULL       ST3P
2011-06-01 03:20:25 2011-06-01 03:40:42 0            0         0         NULL       ST3P
2011-06-01 03:40:42 2011-06-01 03:40:48 0            0         0         0          ST3P
2011-06-01 03:40:48 2011-06-02 02:30:37 0            0         0         12         ST3P
2011-06-02 02:30:37 2011-06-03 12:25:03 0            0         0         0          ST3P
2011-06-03 12:25:03 2011-06-03 13:58:22 0            0         0         13         ST3P
2011-06-03 13:58:22 2011-06-03 19:29:43 0            0         0         0          ST3P
2011-06-03 19:29:43 2011-06-03 19:49:08 0            0         0         13         ST3P
```

Comment: Definitely you have a problem if your DateTime column is not unique - then the resultsets on the same set of data can vary from run to run

Comment: Since they're from a Historian database, the Datetime column are unique, and ordered asc as well (by default), so the results came out consistently. This "WideHistory" table is not a normal table, it's a generated table rather by the platform

Answer (score 0):

If the table `WideHistory` has any unique key, then you can use the subquery for retrieving the "next-row's column" value without needs of `ROW_NUMBER()`

**BUT**

the first column of unique key should be your DateTime column

**UPD:**

Since the DateTime **stated** as unique you may rewrite the script:

```
SELECT TOP 20000
  StartQ.DateTime AS StartTime,
  StartQ.EndTime AS EndTime,
  StartQ.PlyRemaining,
  StartQ.PlyTarget,
  StartQ.PlyNumber as PlyNumber,
  StartQ.PileNumber AS PileNumber,
  'ST3P' AS STACKER_ID
FROM
( SELECT 
    *
FROM 
OpenQuery(INSQL, 'SELECT [DateTime], 
PlyRemaining = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS_TO_STACK],
PlyTarget = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS],
PlyNumber = [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS] - [DA2.N_SMSP_ST3P_PLYS_TO_STACK],
PileNumber = [DA2.N_ST3P_PILENUM]
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [DateTime]
    FROM WideHistory
    WHERE DateTime > HostTab.DateTime
    AND wwRetrievalMode = "Delta"
    ORDER BY [DateTime]
) AS ENdTime
FROM WideHistory as HostTab
WHERE DateTime > "2011-06-01 00:00:00"
AND DateTime <= "2011-12-12 00:00:00"
AND wwRetrievalMode = "Delta"
')  ) StartQ
```

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. I'm not sure I totally understand what you meant, however when I just do a single table output (i.e. without self joining), it came out with only [DateTime],[Tag1_Value],[Tag2_Value] etc. therefore I cannot find any unique key....

Comment: Added script, but sorry in advance about possible errors - I have no data to test it on. 8-)

Comment: No worries mate, the script would have worked fine with normal T-SQL, just this InSQL is a pain in the A** and wouldn't do with "TOP", I'm not even sure whether a (SELECT ) AS ColumnName would work. Essentially every neat trick has to be done out of the ' SELECT ' (Quoted region), inside the quoted there's not much we can do.
Thanks heaps mate, awaiting for respond

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

1) selecting from your openquery as the source table, add/aggregate all your numbers and group them by the datetime value so you have unique datetimes and dump this into a Temp table by performing a select into.

2) now that you have unique  datetime values, proceed to grab the next datetime value using the method of your choice, selecting from the temp table. By using the temp table (or equivalent storage of choice) you save yourself from making the database perform two executions of the same query.

3) I would then grab the next datetime value like so (in SQL Server 2008):

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.EndTime from #TheTempTable T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 X.StartTime as EndTime from #TheTempTable X WHERE T1.StartTime < X.StartTime ORDER BY X.StartTime ASC) T2
```

Hope this helps